# Viewpager strange behavior

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have three fragment (let's call them Left, Middle and Right for the example)

LeftFragment's onPause() is called only when I go to the RightFragment (and not MiddleFragment). And onResume() is called when I go back to MiddleFragment.

(And vice-versa)

Is it the normal behavior ?

Comment: Yes, this is the default behaviour of Fragment inside ViewPager

Comment: Thanks for your response
So, If i have to refresh my database when I go to my left fragment, how can I do it without having to go to the right fragment (to call onResume())

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you on the middle fragment, Android OS will keep Left and Right fragment ready for you to swipe.

If you are on fisrt fragment, then second fragment will be loaded and if on last then second last fragment will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your explain 
So how can I refresh my LeftFragment without have to go to the RightFragment ?

Comment: I did't understand what you are trying to explain.